# Asker accepted my incomplete answer because they changed their approach to the problem

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

This is a bit of an odd question, because I'm questioning whether I myself should have been given an extra 15 rep, however:

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41763170/6530111) a question this morning, with what I believed to be the correct code to solve the users problem.

The answer initially got upvoted, but not accepted, and the OP posted a comment pretty much saying it was working to a better standard than what they had managed, but didn't quite fix the issue.

When trying to work out why/how to fix the last bit, I then got another reply, and +15 rep, where the user said they had changed their mind about the way they wanted the report they were producing to function, and accepted my answer.

But, I'm just wondering - Should my answer have *technically* been accepted? It didn't totally solve the original problem, and the OP then changed the way the application was going to work, so it didn't fix the problem at all in the end.

Should the answer have been accepted in this case? It may not be much help to future users, if any stumble across it... I can understand if I had fixed the issue totally but the OP changed their methodology anyway, but to only fix it 95% makes me question it.

Comment: *"Should my answer have technically been accepted?"* Doesn't matter. OP alone decides if and which answer s/he accepts. Nothing we can or should do about it.

Comment: Why did you post an answer that doesn't actually answer the question in the first place?

Comment: @Servy The code itself usually would have worked, but there must have been some underlying, background line of code that was changing the way the grid functioned. It solved it 99%, but there was something the OP didn't mention that was stopping the column captions from updating.

Comment: @David If the question is lacking a proper reproducible example and doesn't have enough information to answer the question then work to clarify the question, rather than posting an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Servy I agree with the first half of your comment (working to improve the question).  Regarding the second half of your comment, he couldn't know a priori that his answer was incomplete because, as "there was something the OP didn't mention..."

Still, I like your idea of clarifying the question (and possibly even the answer).

Comment: If you're worried that the answer doesn't fully address the question as asked (contrary to what OP's acceptance might imply) then perhaps edit-in a summary of those comments: something like "while this answer helped, it didn't completely answer the original question (noting any known gaps / reasons why). In the end, the OP approached the problem from a different perspective."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Occasionally the poster of a question accepts the "wrong" answer, whether through misunderstanding or another reason. There's not really anything anyone can do about it. I suppose you could leave a comment: "Thanks for the accept, but $OTHER_ANSWER probably solves your problem better, it explains the $FOO better and its technique for $BARring is less likely to..."

You can still edit your answer to fill in the missing pieces if you're so inclined. You could also post another answer if you think of a completely different solution.

Although I commend your concern for future readers (that's what the site is all about, after all), there's no need for you to feel guilty. If you've done the best that you can with your answer, then the checkmark is the asker's responsibility. Over time, up/down voting on the answers will show what everyone else found useful.

Comment: Check mark says "... or most helpful in finding solution" - it really may mean that completely "wrong" answer *should* be accepted if OP got most inspiration from that particular answer. Which is somewhat unfortunate side of "accepted" mark....

Answer (score 18):

The OP is free to accept for whatever reason they want.

End of story.

Comment: I guess so, I just felt like I'd not fully resolved the issue and therefore neither the OP or future users would have total resolution from it!

Comment: @David Amend your answer to point out shortcomings and possible solutions.

Comment: @David - the accept just means that the OP found the answer helpful to them. That is all that should be read into it.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer **answered the question** and **solved the problem** described in the question. The fact that the question didn't accurately represent the OP's problem is not your fault and you couldn't have known that to be the case: there were no indications like the obvious "error message mentions line 17 but OP only posted 8 lines" stuff we see much too often.

Typically, the way this pans out is that after a laborious back and forth, the OP changes his question to accurately match the problem, invalidating all existing answers and leading to lots of frustration.

In your case, the OP changed the problem to match the question, such that your answer solves his problem. That is a highly unusual approach, but there is nothing wrong per se. Now, your answer not only answers the question and solves the problem in the question, it *also* **solves the OP's problem**.

Which is as it should be.